# Char to char* C++

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion, constants

I'm having an error with my constructor in my classes.

In my .cpp file I've got:

```
Player::Player()
{

    m_name="Jane";
    m_amt=100;
}
```

and in my .h file I've got:

```
// Default constructor, does nothing.
    Player();

    // Creates a Player. Player name and amount.
    Player(const char &name, int amt);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
  m_name="Jane";
```

So I tried converting it to a `*char` but that still doesn't work. Can someone help please?

Comment: `const char &` is a reference to a *single character*, not an array of them.

Comment: Would I just get rid of the `const`?

Comment: that would be still a reference to a single character.

Comment: Can you show us how `m_name` is declared? Also - why not use `std::string`?

Answer (score 4):

You can either take a pointer:

```
Player(const char* name, int amt) { ... }
```

and you could use `std::string` to store the name and use `char*` just to construct this string:

```
private:
    std::string m_name;
public:
    Player(const char* name, int amt) : m_name(name) { }
```

or just use `std::string` everywhere and pass by reference to avoid redundant copies being created:

```
private:
    std::string m_name;
public:
    Player(const std::string& name, int amt) : m_name(name) { }
```

Note that the last version is quite flexible and it's possible to also pass `const char*` to it, example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Player {
private:
    std::string m_name;
public:
    Player(const std::string& name) : m_name(name){}
    void printName() { std::cout << m_name; }
};

int main() {
    Player p("Liho");
    p.printName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show your full class/code. Following compiles fine for me.

cpp file...

```
#include"player.h"

Player::Player()
{
    m_name="Jane";
    m_amt=100;
}
```

.h file...

```
class Player {

public:
        // Default constructor, does nothing.
        Player();

        // Creates a Player. Player name and amount.
        Player(const char *name, int amt);

private:
        char* m_name;
        int m_amt;

};
```

Comment: Assigning literal to char *

Comment: @codah what about it?